# Looking for a REST with JSON client library

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest, .net-3.5

I need to connect to an endpoint that serves out JSON via REST interfaces. I can't really find anything that combines these 2 technologies in a coherent manner.

I am looking for a library that will let me get started quickly.

Comment: A few blogs show how to do this using WCF https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=wcf+rest+json

Comment: @oleksii Most of the links detail how to create a service that hands out JSON.  I need a library for easily consuming it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) library and this [extension class](http://pastebin.com/6b2fLChA) that makes use of `DynamicObject`

Some usage examples:

```
public static void GoogleGeoCode(string address)
{
    string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=";
    dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + address).GetDynamicJsonObject();

    foreach (var result in googleResults.results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + result.geometry.location.lat + "," + 
                                result.geometry.location.lng + "] " + 
                                result.formatted_address);
    }
}

public static void GoogleSearch(string keyword)
{
    string url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=8&q=";
    dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + keyword).GetDynamicJsonObject();

    foreach (var result in googleResults.responseData.results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            result.titleNoFormatting + "\n" + 
            result.content + "\n" + 
            result.unescapedUrl + "\n");
    }
}

public static void Twitter(string screenName)
{
    string url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=" + screenName;
    dynamic result = new Uri(url).GetDynamicJsonObject();
    foreach (var entry in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.name + " " + entry.status.created_at);
    }
}

public static void Wikipedia(string query)
{
    string url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + query +"&format=json";
    dynamic result = new Uri(url).GetDynamicJsonObject();

    Console.WriteLine("QUESTION: " + result[0]);
    foreach (var entry in result[1])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ANSWER: " + entry);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is another sample without `DynamicObject`

```
public static void GoogleSearch2(string keyword)
{
    string url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=8&q="+keyword;

    using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
        string jsonStr = wc.DownloadString(url);
        JObject jObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);
        foreach (JObject result in jObject["responseData"]["results"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                result["titleNoFormatting"] + "\n" +
                result["content"] + "\n" +
                result["unescapedUrl"] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with .NET 3.5 as per tag, thus can't use `dynamic`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. But you can still use Json.Net library to parse the json strings returned (`JObject.Parse` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`)

Comment: @AngryHacker, I edited my answer, avoiding .NET4 features.

Answer (score 4):

I would take a look at [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). It's very straight forward to get up and running and has an active following.

Getting started guide: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki

Deserialization: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

Answer (score 1):

The HttpCLient and the JSONValue Type from the WCF Web API should get you on your way. Download the source and look at the samples. There are many samples for working with JSON on the client. http://wcf.codeplex.com/releases

Also see

http://blog.alexonasp.net/

Answer (score 1):

[ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) is probably one of the easiest ways to do this.

**Background**: ServiceStack.Text is an independent, dependency-free serialization library that contains ServiceStack's text processing functionality

**Example**

```
using ServiceStack.Text;

//  Create our arguments object:
object args = new
{
   your = "Some",
   properties = "Other",
   here = "Value",
};

var resultString = fullUrl.PostJsonToUrl(args);
results = resultString.Trim().FromJson<T>();
```

The `PostJsonToUrl` and `FromJson` extension methods are some nice syntactic sugar in my opinion.