# WatiN: Error when trying to TypeText("WatiN") to Google's search text box

Tags: c#, watin

I just recently started looking into WatiN and was following the example from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WatiN.aspx. Unfortunately, I am running into an issue where it is claiming that a text field with the name "q" does not exist.

Here is my code:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IE ie = new IE();
        ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
        TextField ietxt = ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q"));
        ietxt.TypeText("WatiN");
        ie.Button(Find.ByValue("Google Search")).Click();

    }
```

When it gets to the line ietxt.TypeText("WatiN") it throws the error:
"Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'name' equals 'q' at google.com/ (inner exception: Element wasn't available within 30 seconds.)"

It seems that everyone uses this example and it works fine for them. Also I went into the source code for google.com and found exactly where it states that "q" is indeed the name of the search text field.

```
<input name="q" title="Search" class="gsfi" id="lst-ib" ....>
```

Does anyone have any idea why I could be getting this error?

Comment: It seems that anything using the Find statement isn't working.

Comment: If your intention is to make `google searches` you might want to see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8390150/932418

Comment: Thanks, but my intention is to learn WatiN so I can use it for web application testing. I am merely trying to get a working example right now. This code is straight from WatiN resources so there must be some reason why this isn't working for me...

Comment: This is crazy... I've been searching non stop for an answer with no success. I can't seem to access any element on a web page. For instance, ButtonCollection buttons = ie.Buttons even throws an "Element wasn't available" error... so frustrating!

Comment: You are going to have to give us more info. The code you have there is working fine for me. I am using VS 2010 with Watin 2.1.0.1196. Is IE opening for you, can you see it? I am running it in a WPF application. Perhaps it relates to the project type that you are using?

Comment: I also just tried a VS 2010 console application with [STAThread] and it still worked fine.

Comment: Peter, I am also using VS 2010 with Watin 2.1.0.1196. I am running this in a C# Console Application. IE is opening for me fine but whenever I try to access any element on the page I get that error. Could this be some issue in how I installed WatiN?

Comment: @peter I forgot to mention that my project's target framework is .NET Framework 4 and not .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for this! From further testing I came to the conclusion that the issue seemed to be coming from how IE 8 was configured on my machine. I tested on other machines with xp and IE8, and everything was working fine. Uninstalling and reinstalling IE8 has cleared up the issue.

I'm still not sure what was configured differently with my past version of IE8, so if anyone has any ideas of what could have caused this I'll be delighted to hear.

Thanks!