# How should a complex Json response be decoded?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on decoding a json response that's pretty complicated. I've been using Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>()`, but the class I've been deserializing to, RootObject, is getting massive. There are tons of sub-classes (seriously, like 35), and a half-dozen different uses of the sub-class "item." I've been trying to accommodate all of the possible responses using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and sample responses. I'm also trying to stick with simple, reusable methods, so I don't need to have a different `DeserializeObject` call for each type of response.

- Is it possible to convert to a primitive and maintain the response's object depth?
- Am I really going about this in the best way? It doesn't feel like it

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered splitting up the object into smaller pieces that can be requested separately? It's unusual for a client to require a massive amount of data all at once.

Comment: You can make use of `dynamic` instead of deserializing to some complex object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389420/looking-for-a-rest-with-json-client-library/8390150#8390150

Comment: @L.B write that up as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `dynamic` instead of deserializing to some complex object. See [Looking for a REST with JSON client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389420/looking-for-a-rest-with-json-client-library/8390150#8390150)