# How to get Address name using GPS with wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I can get the current GPS coordinates on Windows Phone 7 using GeoCoordinateWatcher class as shown on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28VS.92%29.aspx), I can only get *Latitude* and *Longitude* values, but I want to get **Address** of that location. There is a free application on market named "Where Am I" it shows Address names too, so I think its possible.

How I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google or Yahoo APIs

> http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=20.0,2.0&output=json&oe=utf8&sensor=true&key=**YOURKEY**
>
> http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=20.0,2.0&flags=J&gflags=R&appid=**YOURKEY**

Here is a sample json response from Google

```
{
    "name": "20.00,2.00",
    "Status": {
        "code": 200,
        "request": "geocode"
    },
    "Placemark": [
        {
            "id": "p1",
            "address": "Adrar des Ifôghas, Mali",
            "AddressDetails": {
                "Accuracy": 0,
                "AddressLine": [
                    "Adrar des Ifôghas"
                ]
            },
            "ExtendedData": {
                "LatLonBox": {
                    "north": 22.6604651,
                    "south": 17.2938071,
                    "east": 6.0979005,
                    "west": -2.0979005
                }
            },
            "Point": {
                "coordinates": [
                    2,
                    20,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT**

You can use WebClient to get the result

```
WebClient w = new WebClient();
string page = w.DownloadString(url);
```

Here are the samples to parse the Json result

[Google Maps v3 geocoding server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942095/google-maps-v3-geocoding-server-side)

[Looking for a REST with JSON client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389420/looking-for-a-rest-with-json-client-library)

Comment: how I use that apis in c# application?